# Postgres weighted average given two time intervals columns and separate table

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, weighted

I want to calculate a weighted average for parent orders comprised of several child orders. The first table defines the parent orders where the product id, parent order, start_time and end time are defined. The second table is where I need to aggregate the data.

Groups Definition Table:

```
id | order_Parent |     start_time      |   end_time
1  |      1       | 2018-01-26 15:53:00 |   2018-01-26 15:54:00
2  |      2       | 2018-01-26 15:51:00 |   2018-01-26 16:01:00
2  |      3       | 2018-01-26 15:27:00 |   2018-01-26 15:35:00
```

Data Table To Calculate Weighted Average :

```
id |  order_child  |    time_stamp        |   weight | target_value
1  |       1       | 2018-01-26 15:53:00  |   100    |  99.99
1  |       1       | 2018-01-26 15:53:00  |   200    |  89.99
1  |       1       | 2018-01-26 15:53:30  |   50     |  114.99
2  |       2       | 2018-01-26 15:49:00  |   100    |  49.99
2  |       2       | 2018-01-26 15:55:00  |   100    |  59.99
2  |       2       | 2018-01-26 15:57:30  |   250    |  54.99
2  |       3       | 2018-01-26 15:27:30  |   100    |  54.99
2  |       3       | 2018-01-26 15:31:30  |   75     |  49.99
2  |       3       | 2018-01-26 15:34:30  |   100    |  54.99
```

Ideal Output:

```
 id | order_Parent |     start_time      |   end_time            | WgtAvg
 1  |      1       | 2018-01-26 15:53:00 |   2018-01-26 15:54:00 | 96.41
 2  |      2       | 2018-01-26 15:51:00 |   2018-01-26 16:01:00 | 54.99
 2  |      3       | 2018-01-26 15:27:00 |   2018-01-26 15:35:00 | 53.62
```

The problem seems clear, but I am stumped on how to use the first table for my group definitions in order to calculate the weighted average per parent order.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: whats your formula for weighted average?

Comment: the weighted average formula is SUM(value*weight) * 1/sum(weight). I am seeking a query that for each order_parent, find the order child between start_time and end time and produce a weighted average.